# I cant install Bower with npm 2.7.4

Tags: javascript, node.js, bower, bower-install

My env is Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm using node v0.12.2.. I have installed node  via nvm tool..

When Bower is installing, the errors is getting..

```
npm install -g bower
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
```

I have waited long time to finish installing but it is never finished! I have tried do that many times, I was not able to install Bower..

My npm version is 2.7.4. How can I install bower? There is a different way of installing Bower?

Comment: Are you able to install other node modules fine (i.e. is it just Bower that can't be installed)?

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 Now I was tried to install Coffee module. It is installed very well..  Again I was tried to install bower. It seen same error massage like my shares before..